# Display 30 Dollar Value IN Bitcoin from blockchain.info, File_Get_Conents no longer works?

Tags: php, bitcoin, blockchain

I used to run code:

`<?php echo file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=30"); ?>`

In order to simply display how much 30 dollars in bitcoin is currently worth, I noticed this stopped working.

When I visit the URL I get the bitcoin value, so I figured it must be my webserver that's blocked from reaching blockchain.info. When I visit the URL using my web hotel IP I get this:

> Please use our onion link https://blockchainbdgpzk.onion/

This server is not on a tor network so onion IP is not reachable... What am I doing wrong? Is the fault on my side or their side? Are there any alternative ways of displaying the value that doesn't query their servers?

Answer (score 0):

It appears my server must have been on a ip block that is flagged by blockchain.info as a tor node, i have no idea how this occurred but that's the only explanation i have, i managed to get another ip block from same web hotel now and it works with file_get_contents, odd.